# Why Flutter is not handling this intent from Youtube?

Tags: flutter

So, on this [Flutter for Android devs](https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter) there's some code handling incoming intents from externals applications.

The first issue is that it only works on the first time the app receives an intent, ie. I'm sharing a website from Chrome to my app, the second time I do this with a different page the app will fail to handle the intent.

The second case is when I share a video from Youtube, the app will not receive the intent at all.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, were you able to find any solution?

Comment: My app is not even being shown on the list of apps which can handle that intent.

Comment: HI @Dennis, sorry, I wasn't able to find a solution and gave up shortly after, but my app was listed as an option to share data.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda found the solution, the information provided inside the [flutter docs](https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter) is somewhat vague. But actual [android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive) helped me to find the solution.

What you have to do is provide two different `intent-filter`s so successfully display the app's icon in the launcher and make it listen to external intents.

```
<activity
    --->
  <meta-data
      android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
      android:value="true"/>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Is it working as you expected then? I won't be able to try it anytime soon, unfortunately.

Comment: it did, I tested it on my own :)